# Getting only one entry in csv. Python beautifulsoup ,requests, selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape some data. Checking it with print and getting multiple prints..However, the CSV has only one entry. Can you help please? Thanks a lot.

```
import csv
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver


job_Details = []
job_links = []



chrome_options = Options()
'''chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")'''
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/bin/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.get(f'https://remotejobs.world/')
'''SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 20'''
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
divs = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')
for div in divs:
    job_Details.append(div)
    link = div.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    job_links.append(link)

for job_detail, job_link in zip(job_Details, job_links):
    if job_detail and job_link:
        print(job_link.get_attribute('href'))
        print(job_detail.text)
        url = job_link.get_attribute('href')
        new_page = requests.get(url).text
        time.sleep(2)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(new_page, 'html.parser')
        job_desc = soup.find('div', class_='w-full md:w-2/3')
        if job_desc:
            print(job_desc.text) #Successful Prints.
            dict = {'Job_title and Company': job_detail.text, "Job link": job_link.get_attribute('href'),
                        "Job Details": job_desc.text}
            with open('remoteWORLD.csv', 'w') as f:
                w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict.keys())
                w.writeheader()
                w.writerow(dict)
```

Comment: Because you have `with open('remoteWORLD.csv', 'w') as f:` within your for loop so you'll only get the last entry in your CSV file.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel When I move it outside it says Dict might be undefined?

Comment: You only need `dict` for the header row and the keys are fixed! And I suggest you rename `dict` as it shadows the builtin.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Can you please check..it is writing the first entry in the third column..

Comment: Look at your `dict = {...}` line. `'Job_title and Company': job_detail.text` and `"Job Details": job_desc.text`. If that's wrong then you need to switch the values.

Comment: BTW, that's from your original code.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel No, that's not wrong..I am saying ..it is not printing the job_desc.text at all..

Comment: Do you mean `print(job_desc.text)` does not print? If so, then your condition `if job_desc:` is False meaning your soup.find(...) returned None which requires you to post a new question.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel It prints it successfully, just not in the csv/dict. You can run it and check it yourself, if possible for you.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel It is kind of truncating the print..I don't know why..It's a comparatively larger amount of text..could that be the reason?

Comment: Open the CSV in a text editor. My guess is the "text" contains a whole bunch of whitespace and what you are using to view (Excel?) the CSV cannot display the data.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Damn!..that makes sense...Let me check.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel You are right..I couldn't have have thought of it myself though..would have remained stuck..Thanks a ton.

Comment: When in doubt, always open a text editor. I recommend Notepad++.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel :) ..Checked it in NP++ ..I like it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below how simple my suggestion was.

```py
with open('remoteWORLD.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, ['Job_title and Company', "Job link", "Job Details"])
    w.writeheader()
    for job_detail, job_link in zip(job_Details, job_links):
        if job_detail and job_link:
            print(job_link.get_attribute('href'))
            print(job_detail.text)
            url = job_link.get_attribute('href')
            new_page = requests.get(url).text
            time.sleep(2)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(new_page, 'html.parser')
            job_desc = soup.find('div', class_='w-full md:w-2/3')
            if job_desc:
                print(job_desc.text) #Successful Prints.
                dict = {'Job_title and Company': job_detail.text, "Job link": job_link.get_attribute('href'),
                            "Job Details": job_desc.text}
                w.writerow(dict)
```

Comment: This is not writing the `job_desc.text` though..It is large amount of text..What do I need to change?

Comment: It is writing the `job_detail.text` in that column.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`with open('remoteWORLD.csv', 'a+') as f:`

The w will rewrite the file each time.
The a means you can append (the + means it can be read as well as written).

Check here for more explanations:
[Difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+ in built-in open function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function)

EDIT: or as Justin says, move it outside of the loop and write your lists `job_Details` and `job_links` to it

Comment: a+ works...I think ..will just confirm and accept.

Comment: Sure if you like the header row repeated within your CSV.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel So, I need to write the list to dict? after moving out of loop?

Comment: The line:    `w.writeheader()`    can be removed from the for loop if the header shouldn't be repeated, and replaced above with a 'w' instance of the file.